# Java Native Access in JDK 1.3

Tags: java, dll, nio, jna

I'm trying to integrate JNA into JDK 1.3 application. JNA pages have following on this subject:

> Supported on 1.4 or later JVMs
>   (earlier VMs may work with stubbed NIO
>   support)

I've managed to port JNA sources to JDK 1.3 by dropping all java.nio references. I do not need for example java.nio.Buffer.

However, JNA DLLs are compiled to use Java NIO types and complain accodingly:

> JNA: Problems loading core IDs:
>   java.nio.Buffer

What do I need to do to make JNA work in JDK 1.3? What does this "may work with stubbed NIO support" mean?

Is my only option to stub NIO from C source code and recompile DLL? Since I'm not good at C programming at all, I'm desperately trying to avoid it.

Is there some other way to call native DLL in Java (not JNI, called DLL's are closed source and JNI incompatible).

Comment: I wonder if by stubbed NIO support they mean simply to create your own java.nio classes with method stubs for the NIO class methods that are needed by the compiler (methods that of course you can not use). I doubt that you need to write C code for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The docs are proposing that you write some fake `java.nio` classes, and put them on the `bootclasspath` -- and then don't use anything that requires `java.nio`. You're not expected to modify the JNA source or edit the native code.

Comment: upvoted.In addition to this answer-you probably don't need to change any native c code. either do what this answer proposes or try using this version of JNA http://java.net/jira/browse/JNA-108 . The author stripped out NIO so you don't have to.

Answer (score 4):

JDK 1.3?  That's ridiculously [out of support](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/download-142260.html), unless you're running on Solaris 8.  EOL started *seven years ago* and was complete when JDK 6 [became available](http://download.java.net/jdk6/archive/b105/index.html) on 6-Nov-2006.  That's almost *five years back*.

Personally, I think your efforts would be better spent porting the code to a more modern JDK.  JNA is telling you that it requires NIO.  I'd heed the call and port away from JDK 1.3.

Comment: The Collections API was introduced in JDK 1.2 .

Comment: Not the version with generics.  It doesn't change the point.  Are you arguing in favor of sticking with JDK 1.3?  I think that's crazy.

Comment: I'm assuming he has some reason to use 1.3 -- perhaps, like you say, to run on Solaris 8, or some other old OS. In any case, you didn't say 1.3 doesn't have generics, you said it doesn't have Collections, which it definitely does.

Comment: Got me there, EFH.  You are absolutely correct, and your down vote is warranted.  I don't have a problem with that.  As you can see, I've edited my incorrect answer to reinforce your point.  But the rest still stands.

Comment: All this is meant to run on Oracle JInitator on a thin  Forms 6i client. Legacy, you know.